# wp_signon returns user but the user is not logged in because wp installed on subdomain. How to make it work?

Tags: api, cookies

I am using the WordPress API to get the user login. My code:

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('wp-blog-header.php');

$creds = array();
$creds['user_login'] = 'user';
$creds['user_password'] = 'password';
$creds['remember'] = true;
$user = wp_signon( $creds, false);
if ( is_wp_error($user) )
   echo $user->get_error_message();

$cookie = wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID); ?>
```

these codes are working on my main domain `www.mydomain.com`
but i installed wordpress on `blog.mydomain.com`

I think there is a cookie problem. I tested the codes above on subdomain and i got *user logged in*.

So how can i solve the problem?

P.s : there isnt problem with including "wp-blog-header.php"

Comment: Please do not edit titles to indicate solved status. Also, please place solutions as an **answer**, rather than as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem. Here's the solution.

Add this line to your wp-config.php :

```
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '.yourdomain.com');
```

save the file and upload. That's all.

Answer (score -1):

Visit [Cookie settings for session across WPML subdomains using custom AJAX login](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/202932/cookie-settings-for-session-across-wpml-subdomains-using-custom-ajax-login?newreg=245ec7882e6748198f3a7ef5bdceb1aa)
I think you must add the subdomain to **allowed_http_origins** filter also check the request URL must be from blog.mydomain.com and request Origin and Referer.